# How to run animation sequences more than single time

Tags: android

I am using sequence for animation in my project. I have set onClickListener to that image where I put animation sequences. now when first time I run the code, and click on image, it start run animation correctly but then it never run again on click. I have to again run the code. So how I can run animation sequences more than one time? I have put my codebelow to start animation sequence.

> image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
>
> ```
>       @Override           
>       public void onClick(View v) {
>
>           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>
>           animation_door = (AnimationDrawable) image.getBackground();
>           animation_door.start();
> ```
>
> }       });

Comment: Show your xml for animation also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, before clicking your button again you have to stop the animation also, so you can try it like this,

```
 image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override           
            public void onClick(View v) {

                animation_door = (AnimationDrawable) image.getBackground();
                animation_door.stop();
                animation_door.start();         
              }
          });
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your animation set as a oneShot? It's most likely in the end state and you just need to hint it back to the start state.

```
AnimationDrawable door = (AnimationDrawable) image.getBackground();
door.setOneShot(false);
door.start();
```

Keep in mind this will most likely lead to a looping animation, which you probably don't want.  You could consider using an [Animation Set](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationSet.html) instead since you'll have a bit more control over the animation itself.

Comment: Thanks,...but I want oneshot animation on click, therefore I have set oneshot in xml. Is there any way to make animation clickable,means on each click it should start animation??..thanks in advance.